# Нужно создать стек слов..Вывести слово минимальной длины. Если таких слов несколько,вывести первое введенное слово

Tags: c++, стек

**Нужно создать стек слов. Добавлять в стек слова, пока не будет введен 0.Вывести слово минимальной длины. Если таких слов несколько,вывести первое введенное слово**

Кусок программы есть, чтоб вводить слова до нуля, помогите с реализацией второй части программы.

```
       #include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <deque>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int d,i=0;
    system("chcp 1251");        
    system("cls");
    stack <string> Words;
    stack <string> minWords;
    string a;
    do {

        cout << "Введите слово" << endl;
        cin>>a;
        if(i<d)
        {
            i=d;
            minWords.push(a);
        }
        d = strlen(a.c_str());
        Words.push(a);
    }
    while (a[0] != '0');
    Words.pop();
    cout << "Самое короткое слово: " << minWords.top();
    getchar(); getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Стек не приспособлен для того, чтобы в нем искать заданный элемент.

Comment: Я понимаю, но это задали в вузе, еще преподаватель говорил, что можно как-то через get_container сделать, но я не особо в этом шарю

Comment: Вы можете это сделать во время ввода слов(считать их длину) ну или после того как всё введёте разобрав каждый элемент в стеке(Words.top() ;Words.pop())

Comment: @mkolmi get_container - это не стандартное расширение библиотеки компилятора Microsoft. Компиляторы других производителей могут не поддерживать этот метод.

Answer (score 1):

Метод `get_container`, который вы упомянули в одном из комментариев к своему вопросу,  - это специфическое расширение Microsoft стандартной библиотеки C++.

Поэтому этот метод не может использоваться в программе, которая удовлетворяет стандарту C++.

В общем случае вы можете создать свой класс, который является производным от класса `std::stack<std::string>`, который будет иметь доступ к нижележащему контейнеру, так как последний объявлен со спецификатором доступа `protected`.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

class Helper : public std::stack<std::string>
{
public: 
    Helper( const std::stack<std::string> &stack ) : std::stack<std::string>( stack )
    {

    }

    std::string min_element() const
    {
        auto min = std::min_element( std::begin( c ), std::end( c ),
                                     []( const auto &s1, const auto &s2 )
                                     {
                                        return s1.size() < s2.size();
                                     } );

        return min == std::end( c ) ? "" : *min;                                     
    }
};

int main() 
{
    std::stack<std::string> stack(  
        std::stack<std::string>::container_type{ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" } );

    Helper h( stack );

    std::cout << "The minimal word is \"" << h.min_element() << "\"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
The minimal word is "one"
```

Если же вам разрешается использовать метод `get_container` (или `_Get_container` - надо смотреть документацию Microsoft по `std::stack)`, то никакого вспомогательного класса создавать не надо. Вы можете просто получить ссылку на нижележащий контейнер (по умолчанию это стандартный контейнер `std::deque`) и применить стандартный алгоритм `std::min_element`.